# What MSBuild property is set when dotnet-watch is used?

Tags: .net-core, msbuild, dotnet-cli, dotnet-watch

When running `dotnet watch` or `dotnet watch test`, is there a way to know inside of the csproj file that it's running in a watch mode so certain features can be turned on or off?

Answer (score 1):

The MSBuild property `DotNetWatchBuild` will be set to `true` when MSBuild is invoked by `dotnet-watch`. [Here's some more details on the tool.](https://github.com/aspnet/DotNetTools/blob/master/src/dotnet-watch/README.md)

Comment: The file was moved to [`dotnet/sdk` repo](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/blob/0a71034/src/BuiltInTools/dotnet-watch/README.md).

Comment: This is only for the design-time build, not for the actual build:
> "dotnet-watch performs a design-time build to find items to watch. When this build is run, dotnet-watch will set the property `DotNetWatchBuild=true`."